# Почему не получается заменить часть изменённых данных?

Tags: python, pandas, текст

В моих данных присутствует текст в колонке которая называется `FullDescription`. Привел весь текст в этой колонке к нижнему реестру такой командой:

```
FullDescription1 = df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
```

Теперь хочу заменить старую колонку с данными на новую. Пробовал команды:

```
df = df.replace(df['FullDescription'], FullDescription1)
```

и

```
df1 = df.replace(df['FullDescription'], FullDescription1)
```

Но в обоих случаях мой дата сет оставался неизменным и в колонке `FullDescription` слова до сих пор содержали заглавные буквы...

Как заменить изначальные данные на преобразованные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте вот так:

```
df['FullDescription'] = df['FullDescription'].str.lower()
```